# Jackson NoSuchMethodError requiresPropertyOrdering maven with google app engine project at runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to get an app engine maven project running and appear to have found myself in JAR hell. The project has built and run in the past without using maven, but I've had enough of Eclipse's nonsense and am trying to mavenize the project for all the usual reasons.

Currently everything is working compiling and tests are passing (with `mvn clean install` from the `myproject-war` directory [shown here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating)). I'm also able to launch `mvn appengine:devserver` from my `myproject-ear` directory and get the server running. Navigating to one of my servlets, however, I get the `noSuchMethodError` trace shown below. (All code is at the bottom for readability).

This looks similar to [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823106/two-maven-dependency-for-latest-and-old-version-conflicts) where jackson versions weren't in sync. However, my jackson versions seem to be ok, as can be seen in my `pom.xml`, also at the bottom. It appears that that method [didn't appear until Jackson 3.0](http://www.grepcode.com/search/?query=JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering), which again seems ok because of the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | ack jackson` and the fact that I'm depending on `2.4.1`.

The most likely culprit I can think of is the google library, which I'm using because I'm following the [example here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) which appears to rely on it. However, I'm not really sure how to go about testing that hypothesis or getting the google library to work without its dependency. Perhaps the `<exlcudes>` tag, but I'm not sure how I would apply it.

Does anyone have any suggestions or things I'm missing? How can I get the correct version of the class to be used at runtime? Or am I missing something and the solution is something entirely different?

**EDIT**: Note that on the advice of a comment/answer I have ensured that all of the libraries I am responsible for use the same version of fasterxml/Jackson rather than the older codehaus packaing. I agree that it appears that there is still an older dependency somewhere causing problems, but that is precisely the problem I am struggling to correct.

**EDIT 2**: I eventually got this working as I cleaned up the overall project and dependency structure, although I can't provide the exacty fix as to why. I think the issue was due to this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It [has a dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.4.1) on `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.0.6.Final`, which itself [depends on](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider/3.0.6.Final) `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.1`, which doesn't have the missing method, as I pointed out in my original post.

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | ack jackson`:

```
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4.1)
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:test
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:test
```

Exception trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:458)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:379)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(JsonMapperConfigurator.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.locateMapper(ProviderBase.java:856)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:588)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:118)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:99)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<groupId>org.mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-server-war</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1-war</appengine.app.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Our custom common jar. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupdId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0M10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory> 

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I am using Jackson 2.4.1 with GAE 1.9.7 with no problems. You have something that including something on the classpath that you can't see as a transient dependency.

Comment: How does one go about tracking a problem like that down? Also, why the downvote? Happy to ask better questions if I know how.

Comment: remove everything and add things back one at a time until you get the error, then you have found the problem, just like you would debug anything else. My projects all work just fine, your problem is extremely localized to your project.

Comment: Removing things one at a time would be easy if I was seeing the error at compile time. Since I'm getting it at runtime I have to include the projects to build, making it difficult to remove one at a time and isolate the issue. If there's a way to do this I apologize for not knowing it.

Comment: you are mixing ancient versions of dependencies with up to date ones, this will never end well. update to the most recent versions of all the dependencies.

Comment: I've removed all old dependencies in the projects for which I am responsible. They now all use fasterxml 2.4.1, and I get the same error. This makes me again think it is one of my dependencies pulling in an older version--the culprit still seems likely to me to be the googleapi-client dependencies, especially the gson one. Is there any way you can think of to verify, investigate, or try and solve this? It is obvious to you, but not to me. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: This is also a problems with Restlet with GAE, not just Resteasy I think

Answer (score 1):

### This is what is working for me with GAE 1.9.7

#### Properties

```
<properties>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.7</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <resteasy.version>3.0.8.Final</resteasy.version>
    <jackson.version>2.4.1</jackson.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <reflections.version>0.9.9-RC2</reflections.version>
</properties>
```

#### Dependency Management

```
<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Third Party Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>${reflections.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>
```

#### Dependencies

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I've added the `<dependencyManagement>` tag, which I was missing, but still no luck. Neither of the custom projects I depend on use the fasterxml packaging of jackson, although they do use the older codehaus package.

Comment: the older codehaus packages are your problem, they are obsolete and you should move to the latest versions.

Comment: I'll try that approach. I didn't think that would be the problem since it's throwing the error for `com.fasterxml` rather than `org.codehaus`.

Comment: you need to start from a clean slate, no one on the internet can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Works for me :

First , check and remove any libraries with these names in your project:

```
Jackson Databind 
Jackson Core
Jackson Annotations
```

because you may have some of them repeated in your java proyect ..

Second, go here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core
and Download the 3 jars with **this specific**  versions (that 28/04/2016 is the last version) :

```
Jackson Databind  - version 2.73   
Jackson Core   - version 2.73     
Jackson Annotations   - version 2.73
```

Third, imports for your controller

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
...

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

and dont forget your Object with

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "UsuarioDTO")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
...
}
```

-Rebuild/Redeploy(and debug because maybe you will get a different error and may confused with the previous one)